# Twitter datepicker in dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to add a datepicker in dropdown menu. I use this datepicker [link](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Next, I added code to not close the menu when I click on inputs select date, the input disappears. How can i fix it?

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});

$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
$('.jsolr-search-result-form .dropdown input, .jsolr-search-result-form .dropdown label, .jsolr-search-result-form ul span').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do the following:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#dropdownMenu1').parent().on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9qyf2/

Note that the dropdown events are triggered on the parent element. From there on you can check which element has been clicked and prevent the default behavior if desirded. Make sure to check the bootstrap documentation on the js components: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This one was very troublesome. I also have a couple of datepickers located within some Bootstrap drop-down menus. I solved this using two ways.

The first uses jQuery to stop the event from bubbling up one time when the DatePicker is clicked

```
$('.yourDatePicker').on('hide', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.yourDropDown').one('hide.bs.dropdown', function(ev) {
        return false;
    });
});
```

The other, more permant solution was to change the datepicker.js file itself, but it sounds like you are using the datepicker cdn. If you can download it and use it locally, you can crack it open you will find code that looks like this

```
click: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(e.target).closest('span, td, th'),
        year, month, day;
    if (target.length === 1){
        switch (target[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()){
...ect...
```

If you add a e.stopPropagation() function to this area, like this

```
click: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // <-- add this
    var target = $(e.target).closest('span, td, th'),
        year, month, day;
    if (target.length === 1){
        switch (target[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()){
```

your datepickers will stop interfering with your other DOM elements, though this solution is more widespread, and I would test to make sure it doesn't impact other areas in your code.